# About the autocomplete of Qt Creator 2.0.0

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have some questions about Qt creator.

Under Win XP, I can use autocomplete with hot key 'ctrl + whitespace'. Can I change the hot key to another like 'ctrl + shift + u' ? Because the hot key 'ctrl + whitespace' often is used to change my input method.

And under Mac OS X, I installed Qt 4.7 with Qt Creator too. But I cannot find a hot key for autocomplete.

Comment: In Mac OS X, the default hot key is Ctrl-Space just like in Windows, even when you would expect it be Cmd-Space.

Comment: In Mac OS X, the Ctrl-Space is already used by Mac OS, so the hot key doesn't work under Qt. I use the Mihai's method to change the default hot key for autocomplete, and it works well. I don't like Ctrl-Space as hot key under any software, it always is used to change input method for me. I need to type not only English when I works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools -> Options, go to Environment, select the Keyboard tab, then either search for "complete" or scroll to the TextEditor section. Change the CompleteThis command to whatever hotkey you want.